# Brakes fully applied with a light pedal press

Tags: toyota, brakes, camry

I have a 2007 Toyota Camry.

When I start the car after it has completely cooled down, the brakes are applied completely even with a light press of the pedal and the car comes to a sudden stop.

After pressing and depressing the pedal a few times, the brakes start responding properly.

Is this something I should be worried about?

EDIT: I took the vehicle to a mechanic and they didn't find anything wrong, so I'm going to just let it be for now.

Comment: Yes, take it to a repair shop immediately. If you don't feel like you can safely drive it there, get it towed.

Comment: @cory I'll take it tomorrow. It works without any issues after a few press-depress cycles so I don't think I'll have trouble driving it.

Comment: if this is a hybrid, there are a few break related recalls out there which expire in June 30 of this year.

Comment: @RowanHawkins I first read your name as Rowan Atkins :) It's not a hybrid. And I'll be hard pressed to get a recall honored in my country!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is common in many vacuum assisted brake systems.  As long as the brakes operate normally after a few actuations of the brakes, you should be ok. I don't know the exact cause, but believe it has something to do with maintaining the right vacuum boost after startup.  One thing you could do is to tap the brake with a light pedal on, and complete pedal off a couple of times before you start rolling.

FWIW I have several VWs that this happens on, and they are all different in the amount of the initial overboost of the brakes, but all settle down after an application or two of brakes, or simply the passage of a few minutes time.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the site. This is not common behavior. I am not sure what is causing this, but any issues related to brakes should be of concern.

This could be caused by anything from moisture in the system to an ABS issue. Regardless, it would be wise to have it serviced before the problem worsens.

Comment: My initial thoughts were related to moisture or contaminated brake fluid, but the fluid looks good and the issue disappears after a few presses. It's more in line with mongo's answer.

Comment: Just be careful. Any other symptoms present themselves have it looked at. The last thing you want is to have brake failure because of convenient troubleshooting.

Comment: Will do, I get the point about convenient troubleshooting thanks for the heads up.